# Why has GitLab saved one folder of my project as a Subproject commit?

Tags: reactjs, git, gitlab, subproject

I have started developing a website, saved in my local folders, and I am trying to save it to a GitLab repository. I created a new repository on GitLab and then did the following:

```
cd existing_folder
git init --initial-branch=main
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/...
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin main
```

The project comprises two folders, Server and Client, the Client is a React App. However the Client folder is appearing as a red folder icon that can't be opened:

[image: 1]

When I click on the initial commit it says that Client has been added as a Subproject commit:

[image: 2]

I don't know what this means, I have built websites with a similar structure before and Gitlab has not done this. I just want the contents of both Client and Server folders to be saved in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you were doing a git init in the wrong folder. Now your Client folder is maybe a submodule of the actual top git repo.

Check if you have in your Client folder a hidden .git directory

To fix that remove the .git folder in the Client directory. Also check for a file called *.gitmodules* in the top folder and remove it if it exists.

Comment: You mean `.gitmodules` - but rather than just manually removing it, one should consider `git submodule deinit`. (There won't be a `.gitmodules` here though as that would be a proper submodule, and the OP created a broken one instead.)

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved the problem - there were hidden .git directories in both the Client and root folder - I deleted both and initialised to a new repo which solved it.

Answer (score 0):

What you did:

- Created a *Git repository* holding the client side of the app, and committed stuff to that.  This repository resides in `client/.git/`.  It contains files that are presumably named things like `main.js` and so on (or `main.ts` and so on, if TypeScript, etc.).
- Created, in `.git`, a *second, over-arching Git repository* holding the server side of the app, and committed stuff to that.  This repository resides in `.git/` and contains files named `server/functions.js` and so on.  Git will be calling this second over-arching repository a *superproject*.  It's just a Git repository though, albeit one with one special property.

Note that as far as Git is concerned, *folders* don't even *exist:* files just have names with embedded slashes—always *forward* slashes, never backslashes—in them.  Git will convert these to the folder-and-file arrangements that your OS requires, as needed.  This deals with any backslash things that the OS requires as well (e.g., converting names from `foo/bar.js` to `foo\bar.js` on Windows).  But for the most part this is invisible and we can *pretend* that we have folders full of files; we're going to work with OS-level files *extracted from* commits anyway, and those really are files-in-folders.  So for the rest of this we'll pretend we do have folders.

Anyway, for good (security) purposes, Git *refuses to ever store anything named `.git`*.  So all the files in `client/.git/*` *literally cannot be stored:* you cannot put the sub-repository in `client` into the superproject in `.`, even though `./.git` holds `server/` and all those files just fine.

Instead, Git will add to the superproject something that Git calls a *gitlink.*  This is an entry that says: *After you have cloned and checked out a commit for the superproject, clone another Git repository too.  In that new, additional Git repository, I have saved the raw hash ID of the commit you should check out in that sub-project.*

This is why you see that instruction:

> `Subproject commit 327f06...88c`

That's the thing that makes this superproject Git repository a superproject: it contains a *gitlink* named `client`, and the gitlink itself—which is otherwise just like a file—says `327f06...88c`.  That `327f06...88c` hash ID is the hash ID of a commit in the Git repository that Git should clone and place into a `client` folder within the superproject.

Now, the trick here is that for Git to run:

```
git clone <url> client && (cd client && git checkout 327f06...88c)
```

Git is going to need to know the *`url`* to use on this command-line.  The gitlink records only the *commit hash ID and the path name `client`*.  The URL goes into a separate file, as [chickahoona mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70715689/1256452), named `.gitmodules`.

The thing is, when you ran:

```
git add .
```

this will *not* have created the `.gitmodules` file for you.  To create that file, you must use `git submodule add` instead of `git add`.  The `git submodule add` command takes the same kind of argument as `git add`—the name `client` in this case—but *also* takes a URL, which it will add to the `.gitmodules` file in the form that Git will need to run the `git clone` command later.

You won't have to run this `git clone` command on *your* computer, because you already have a Git repository *in* `client/.git`.  So the fact that `git add .` only does half the job doesn't affect *your* use of this superproject/gitlink pairing.  But it means *no one else can use your superproject* because the cloning directive is missing.

What's not clear is whether you, personally, want to store your server and client in two separate Git repositories like this—one a superproject and one a submodule—or whether you want to store this in, say, *three* Git repositories:

- one for the server only,
- one for the client only, and
- one to bind them.<sup>1</sup>

The last one would be the only superproject in the setup, containing *only* two gitlinks and a `.gitmodules` file referring to the two submodules.  The server's files would be in a Git repository stored in `server/.git` and the client's files would be in a Git repository stored in `client/.git` (as they are now).

Or, perhaps you don't want *any* submodules at all.  In this case, you will need to *remove the `client/.git` folder* (or move it elsewhere).  This will destroy (or move elsewhere) the *entire repository containing the client*.  You will, however, retain any *working tree* files from that repository.  Now that the inner repository is *gone*, those working-tree files can be `git add`-ed to what *was* the superproject.  These files will have named like `client/main.js` and Git will create a `client/` folder and extract them to files named `main.js` and the like within that `client/` folder.

**Only you can decide what you want done here.**  Decide and then proceed: either add the submodule correctly, with `git submodule add`, or turn the server into a submodule as well and add that, or remove (or move) the client Git *repository* but not the *current version* of the client files.

---

<sup>1</sup>Three rings for the Elven-kings under the sky,
Seven for the Dwarf Lords in their halls of stone...

Comment: Thanks Torek, I didn't want any submodules I just wanted everything in one folder. Removing the hidden .git folders in the Client and root folders and reinitialising to a new repo solved this.